# Study the pointwise convergence and uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to study the pointwise convergence and uniform convergence of the sequence of functions $$f_n(x)=\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}, \hspace{4mm}x\in \mathbb{R}$$ It is easy to see that
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 1,&\text{if}\, |x|\leq 1\\
 x^2,&\text{if}\, |x|>1
\end{cases}
$$
Since $f(x)$ is continous, we still cannot say anything about the uniform convergence of $f_n(x)$ $($remember that continuity of $f(x)$ is a necessary condition for the uniform convergence of $f_n(x)$$)$.
Now, we have to study separately $$sup_{|x|\leq 1}|f_n(x)-1|\hspace{8mm}(1)$$
and $$sup_{|x|>1}|f_n(x)-x^2|\hspace{8mm}(2)$$
and see if they both tend to zero as $n$ goes to infinity.

We first start with $(1)$. So, by the mean value theorem we get $$|\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}-1|=|\frac{1}{n}(1+x^{2n})^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\cdot 2nx^{2n-1}||x-0|=\frac{2nx^{2n}}{n(1+x^{2n})^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}\leq 2\neq 0$$
So does this prove that $f_n(x)$ is not uniformly convergent? I think I have commited an error somehow. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I have posted an answer to the closely related question [Uniform convergence of a n-th root on $\mathbb{R}^+$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4313975).

Comment: Thanks for spending your time helping me, I couldn't find it.

Comment: Are you saying you couldn't find the question I linked above? [My answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327272) there shows that your sequence of functions converges uniformly (in contradiction to the accepted answer here).

Comment: Yeah, I knew I was doing something wrong. I have edited the question regarding your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem**

It is not the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), which has nothing to do with derivatives, that you are citing, but the [Mean Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), and that is being misquoted, as well.

---

**Applying the Mean Value Theorem**

The Mean Value Theorem says that if $f$ is continuous on $[0,x]$, and differentiable on $(0,x)$, that
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f'(\xi)\tag1
$$
for some $\xi\in(0,x)$.

Therefore, for some $\xi\in(0,x)$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}-1}{x-0}=\frac1n\left(1+\xi^{2n}\right)^{\frac1n-1}2n\xi^{2n-1}\tag2
$$
Thus, for $x\lt1$, as $n\to\infty$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}-1
&=\overbrace{\quad2x\quad\vphantom{{\xi^2}^{\frac1n}}}^{
\lt2}\overbrace{\ \ \ \xi^{2n-1}\ \ \ \vphantom{{\xi^2}^{\frac1n}}}^{\to0}\overbrace{\left(1+\xi^{2n}\right)^{\frac1n-1}}^{\le1}\tag{3a}\\[6pt]
&\le2x^{2n}\tag{3b}
\end{align}
$$
That is, for $|x|\lt1$,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}-1\right)=0\tag4
$$

---

**Applying Bernoulli**

Simpler is to apply [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), which says that for $n\ge1$ and $|x|\le1$,
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt[n]{1+x^{2n}}-1
&\le\frac1nx^{2n}\tag{5a}\\
&\le\frac1n\tag{5b}
\end{align}
$$
This also gives $(4)$.

The case for $x\gt1$ can be handled as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4327272).

Comment: Why in $(3b)$it is $2x^{2n}$ and not $2x$?

Comment: Because $0\lt\xi\lt x$